# How does the acker work if I consume twice from w bolt?

Tags: apache-storm

My topology has boltA which emits once on its default stream. Bolts B and C subscribe to this bolt using shuffle grouping.

How does acking work in this scenario? Wouldn't B and C double ack the tuple, leaving it in an unacked state?

I ask as a sanity check for a weirdly behaving topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple consumers (in your case B and C), Storm knows that the tuples requires and ack from both. Ie, the tuple will only be acked if both consumers ack the tuple a single time each.